# What is the number of simple connected graphs that are sparse (few edges compared to the number of nodes)?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The graphs that I consider are:

1. labelled (so, I do not want to count them up to isomorphism).
2. simple (no loops and at most one edge between two nodes).
3. connected.

In

[How to calculate the number of possible connected simple graphs with $n$ labelled vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154941/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-possible-connected-simple-graphs-with-n-labelle)

there is an answer to the count of such graphs given $n$ vertices.  Would there be a formula of the number of such graphs if the number of vertices $n$ and the number of edges $m$ are given?  My situation is that I need to estimate the number of such graphs when $n$ is large (say 3000), but $m$ is small.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot!