# How can I count the number of ways to connect a graph with $X$ vertices and $Y$ edges?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions

If I have a graph with $X$ vertices, and $Y$ edges, where $Y$ is between $X-1$ and $(X(X-1))/2$, how can I count the number of unique ways to connect the graph (strictly no more than two paths between the two same points)?

Comment: If you're doing Google Foobar [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050076/recursive-formula-for-the-number-of-connected-labelled-graphs-with-n-vertices-an?lq=1) is definitely related (and points to the solution).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we're doing the same challenge ;). So far the best resource I found on this topic is http://oeis.org/A062734 but I'm not sure that the formula/mathematica expression is still valid for n=20 and I have not yet translated it to python. I plan to consult the referenced books, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Link-only answers are discouraged -- can you add some information that answers the question? As it is now this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: You're right, but I would have loved to be able to comment the question instead of "answering" it to give this link, but so far I do not have enough reputation point to comment it. I find it strange that noob are not allowed to comment and get reputation also for pertinent comment vs bad reputation for off topic comment/spam.