# Counting simple, connected, labeled graphs with N vertices and K edges

Tags: graph-theory

Given the number of vertices $n$ and the number of edges $k$, I need to calculate the number of possible non-isomorphic, simple, connected, labelled graphs.

My question is very similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154941/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-possible-connected-simple-graphs-with-n-labelle) one. Quoting the accepted answer:

> This sequence of numbers is A001187 in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. If $d_n$ is the number of labelled, connected, simple graphs on $n$ vertices, the numbers $d_n$ satisfy the recurrence
> $$\sum_k\binom{n}kkd_k2^{\binom{n-k}2}=n2^{\binom{n}2}\;$$
>
> from which it’s possible to calculate $d_n$ for small values of $n$. This recurrence is derived as formula (3.10.2) in Herbert S. Wilf, generatingfunctionology, 2nd edition, which is available for free download [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/DownldGF.html).

### Example

Let's have $n=4$ (vertices) and $k=3$ (edges). Given my limited knowledge, I'm unable to actually calculate the number of graphs by using the formula above.

Can somebody please walk me through it? I was able to manually count 16 different graphs for this example.

### Edit #1

I've found the formula for calculating the total number of simple labelled graphs:
$$\binom{\binom{n}2}m$$
(Handbook of Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics, available [here](https://books.google.si/books?id=yJIMx9nXB6kC&pg=PA580&lpg=PA580&dq=number%20of%20simple%20connected%20labeled%20graphs&source=bl&ots=1Reo0hpaQX&sig=0ljeS2CZl3kDDi81jML-SC7jEx4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YoOSVPjnLIWGzAO7tYDQAg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=number%20of%20simple%20connected%20labeled%20graphs&f=false), Page 580)

The problem is that the number of graphs given by this formula (for the above example is $20$) also includes all the disconnected graphs.

Comment: This should be what I'm looking for: https://www.oeis.org/A144161

Comment: No https: http://www.oeis.org/A144161

Comment: It would appear that this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689526/) is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There is no analytic formula for the number of connected graphs given $n$ labeled nodes and $N$ edges.  It has been known, however, since around $1860$ that for $n$ labeled nodes with $n-1$ edges (e.g. $4$ nodes and $3$ edges) the number of connected graphs is $n^{n-2}$.

For any graph of $n$ labeled nodes and $k\gt\binom {n-1}2$ edges the graph is always connected and thus the number of connected graphs in that case is equal to the total number of graphs.

For any graph of $n$ labeled nodes and $K\lt(n-1)$ edges the graph is never connected.  So the number of connected graphs in that case is always $0$.

It is the connected graphs of $n$ labeled nodes with $(n-1)\le k\le\binom{n-1}2$ edges that are non trivial. Carl Wilhelm Borchardt found the formula that we use for the case of $k=n-1$.  Cayley popularized it by "expanding" the result.

I just recently found another case.  I am currently writing the results now.

Comment: Hey @Keyon L Coleman, did you publish your results ? I would be interested, thanks :D