# Number of different Graphs with n vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A graph has 7 vertices and 7 edges. How many different graphs (non- isomorphic) are possible?

The resulting graph has no constraints. i.e. it can be either connected or disconnected graph.

How can I extend this idea to graph with n vertices and 7 edges?

Comment: By "different", do you mean "nonisomorphic", or literally different?

Comment: question made more clear.

Comment: This kind of question occurs quite a lot - were none of the other answers relevant? Such as this one : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072726/counting-simple-connected-labeled-graphs-with-n-vertices-and-k-edges?rq=1

Comment: @gilleain:  I haven't looked around for other answers, but that one appears to be for connected graphs.  Of course, if you can find the answer for connected graphs (for all $N$ and $K \leq 7$), then disjoint unions will give you the desired graphs.

Comment: I should add that I'm not an expert in this area, and it's possible that there's a nice closed-form answer I don't know of using (e.g.) generating functions.

Comment: The following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/) may prove relevant.

Comment: Do you consider graphs with multiple edges and loops?

Comment: Self loops are allowed but not multiple edges.