# What is the maximum number of simple graphs possible with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges for both labelled and unlabelled cases?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What is the maximum number of simple graphs possible with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges?

The number of edges possible in a simple graph with $n$ vertices would be ${n \choose 2}$. So the total number of possible graphs would involve the total number of subsets possible out of this which would be ${2^{n \choose 2}}$. Now we are restricted to selecting graphs which have only $m$ number of edges. How do I calculate this?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072726/counting-simple-connected-labeled-graphs-with-n-vertices-and-k-edges

Comment: You have $\binom{n}{2}$ locations where edges can be.  To have $m$ edges, you need to pick which $m$ of the $\binom{n}{2}$ locations actually have edges.  There are then $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}$ labeled graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges.