# Number of graphs on labeled vertices that satisfy transitive closure

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The number of unique undirected graphs on $n$ labeled vertices without multiple edges or self-loops is $2^{n \choose 2}$ as the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154941/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-possible-connected-simple-graphs-with-n-labelle) suggests. I would like to know how many of those graphs satisfy [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_graph_theory).

I've been trying to enumerate them all for small number of vertices to get some intuition and I believe for graphs on 3 labeled vertices, there 8 possible undirected graphs (no self-loops and no multiple edges), 5 of which satisfy transitive closure. For 4 vertices, there are 64 possible graphs, 15 of which satisfy transitive closure.

How can I get a closed-form expression that counts the number of unique undirected graphs on labeled vertices with no self-loops and no multiple-edges that satisfy transitive closure?

Comment: Isn't this the same as asking how many equivalence relations there are on a finite set?  When you say they "satisfy transitive closure" I take you to mean that the adjacency relation is transitive.  Since it's always symmetric, and we ca agree to consider it reflexive, we have an equivalence relation.  If that's what you mean, you are looking for the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Comment: @saulspatz Yes I think you're right! This is super helpful to me, thanks!