# How to calculate the number of possible connected simple graphs with n labelled vertices where only one connected to each other vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I saw this question: [How to calculate the number of possible connected simple graphs with $n$ labelled vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154941/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-possible-connected-simple-graphs-with-n-labelle?newreg=fc5eb5d08f2a478cbc822c16f9377e76)

But how can we count graphs with only one dominant vertex (only one vertex in graph that connected to each other node)?

Suppose that we had a set of vertices labelled 1,2,…,n.

In what efficient way do we be able to calculate the number of possible ways the graph can be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $n$ multiplied by the number of graphs on $n-1$ vertices with no dominant vertices.

How many graphs on $n$ vertices have no dominant vertices? this can be obtained via inclusion-exclusion, it yields $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}2^{\binom{n-i}{2}}$

Hence the answer to your question is $n\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}2^{\binom{n-1-i}{2}}$

Comment: Is first formula for graph with all connected vertices? Because we can have situation where  there is two independent graphs connected only by dominant vertex.

Comment: This formula accounts for stars as well, I think that is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, it is. Now everything fine. I just misunderstood at first. Thank you!